# How to use single array in multiple collectionView sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have single array which contain game`s informations. My Json has 12 items in a page. I did created 4 sections which has 3 rows. It is repeating first 3 items of array in every sections.

[Screenshot from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ26j.png)

I want to use like that;

Total Items = 12

1. Section = 1 2 3
2. Section = 4 5 6
3. Section = 7 8 9
4. Section = 10 11 12

How can I do that ? Thanks in advance :)

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return id.count / 3
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "lastAddedCell", for: indexPath) as! lastAddedCell

        cell.gameName.text = name[indexPath.row]
        cell.gameImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:resimUrl[indexPath.row]))

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can maintain the dictionary like you have key value pairs. For example key should be 0,1 and 2 and value should be array of 3 elements each. So in number of sections you need to return dict.count and in number of rows in section you need to fetch the dict elements like dict[indexPath.row].values.count.

Comment: @RajatGupta thanks for suggest, I have to change api from server side for it but I thought there is an easy way for do that :/

Comment: the data source is an array of objects right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's such a good idea. I would rather create the section separately by making a section manager than making them from the same array. But, if you want to do it the way you are doing it right now. Here is an easy fix:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return id.count / 3
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "lastAddedCell", for: indexPath) as! lastAddedCell
    let index = indexPath.row + (indexPath.section * 3) // The index is then based on the section which is being presented
    cell.gameName.text = name[index]
    cell.gameImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:resimUrl[indexPath.row]))

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this case below and implement it,

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

//Statcially you can slice them like this

    var arr2 = array[0...2] {
        didSet {
            //reload your collection view
        }
    }
    var arr3 = array[3...5]
    var arr4 = array[6...8]
    var arr5 = array[9...array.count - 1]
```

Above you manually sliced the `dataSource` for each  `UICollectionView` but the problem is this is really risky and eventually can lead to an `Index Out of Range` crash, so we dynamically slice the array thru looping in it using the index of each element in range of +3 indexes to append to the new  `UICollectionView` data source.

```
    // loop thru the main array and slice it based on indexes
for(index, number) in array.enumerated() {
    if 0...2 ~=  index { // if in range
        arr2.append(number)
    } else
    if index <= 5 {
        arr3.append(number)
    } else
    if index <= 8 {
        arr4.append(number)
    } else
    if index <= 11 {
        arr5.append(number)
    }
}
```

**Finally** : in your `numberOfItemsInSection`  check the `UICollectionView` and set return its data source like,

```
if collectionView = myMainCollectionView { 
return arr3.count 
}
```

And goes the same for the `cellForItemAt`

**Heads Up** : make sure your dataSource arrays are empty initially,

```
let arr2: [Int] = [] { 
 didSet{
  //reload your collectionView 
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer bro, I did solved it thanks to Galo Torres Sevilla`s answer

Comment: yes ill keep it for the additional info might help someone